# which open-source frameworks exist for fact-extraction

Tags: nlp

probably question is silly, but still: what tools one might use to transform an English text to a set of "facts"

for example a sentence "Julius Caesar crossed the Rubicon in 49 BC" would be parsed as something like:

```
{
"subject": "Julius Caesar (person)",
"object": "Rubicon (river)",
"verb": "to cross", 
"verb aspects": ["time": "49BC"]
}
```

or anything remotely close to this

Answer (score 1):

I don't know many examples but I'm aware of at least one such tool, specialized for the medical domain: [SemRep](https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/)

> SemRep is a UMLS-based program that extracts three-part propositions,
>   called semantic predications, from sentences in biomedical text.
>   Predications consist of a subject argument, an object argument, and
>   the relation that binds them. For example, from the sentence in (1),
>   SemRep extracts the predications in (2).
>
> 1.We used hemofiltration to treat a patient with digoxin overdose that was complicated by refractory hyperkalemia.
>
> 2. Hemofiltration-TREATS-Patients,
>      Digoxin overdose-PROCESS_OF-Patients,
>      hyperkalemia-COMPLICATES-Digoxin overdose,
>      Hemofiltration-TREATS(INFER)-Digoxin overdose

In general, this is closely related to the problem of [semantic role labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_role_labeling):

> semantic role labeling (also called shallow semantic parsing) is the process that assigns labels to words or phrases in a sentence that indicate their semantic role in the sentence, such as that of an agent, goal, or result.

Apparently there are some implementations available: https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/ASRL